# awk script for decimal values

Tags: bash, awk

I am using this script to extract lines if `column 7` is `< 1.0E-08` **AND**
column eight has one or more than one values `> 0.2 and 0.3`

Is it the right approach ?

InputFile: `head -1 test.txt`

```
 A2            DR28     P3379          72          7       5.008    8.252e-14 
    0.05132,0.04248,0.002704,0.116,0.04439,0.2,0.3

  A2            DR28     P3379          72          7       5.008    0.05    
   0.05132,0.04248,0.002704,0.116,0.04439,0.006,0.004
```

Script: first I did

```
awk '{if($7 < 1.0E-08 || $8 > 0.2) print}' test.txt
```

This gives the first line as output but i want to use `&& (AND)`  instead of `|| (OR)`

when I use `AND (&&)`

```
awk '{if($7 < 1.0E-08 && $8 > 0.2) print}' test.txt
```

no result though line one fits this criteria.

I also try this but here just considering column eight as a cut-off point

```
awk -F',' '$8 > 0.2' test.txt
```

this script work fine but I need to consider column `7` too as I have few lines in output so just want to make sure that i am not missing anything

Comment: ok @cyrus thank you

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but something like this should work

```
 $ awk 'function anyGreater(x,v) {    
           n=split(x,f8,","); 
           for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(f8[i]>v) return 1; 
           return 0}

        $7<1.0E-08 && anyGreater($8,0.2)' file
```

Comment: Is your 8th field on the same line or is there a line break?

Comment: it is on same line no line break

Comment: changed true/false to 1/0; please try now.